# How can I select only one row for each ID in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table that holds many entries with repeated IDs (for various reasons)
So you might have something like

```
ID TIME DATA
1  xx   xx
2  xx   xx
3  xx   xx
1  xx   xx
3  xx   xx
```

What query can I run through PHP to select each ID only once?
So I would like my result set to look like

```
ID TIME DATA
1  xx   xx
2  xx   xx
3  xx   xx
```

Comment: What would TIME and DATA be in the result? The values of the first record having a specific id (then the question is why)? Or the result of some aggregate function (Count(), Sum() maybe even Group_Concat())? or... what?

Comment: DISTINCT does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a ganders at **SELECT DISTINCT**

Comment: You guys are awesome!
DISTINCT works perfectly. Group By is also good, but I think I need distinct in this case.
Thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: Didn't see that green coming :) Nice.

Comment: Heh, I'd be interested in seeing the actual DISTINCT query that solved this problem!:)

Comment: There isn't much too it Andomar...
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM vote_records WHERE title LIKE '".$query1."' OR title LIKE '".$query2."' OR title LIKE '".$query3."' OR title LIKE '".$query4."' OR title LIKE '".$query5."'";

Comment: @Rudebuyrock ... Would a JOIN on the distinct ids not be better?

Comment: Aaah so you're just looking for the id, not the other columns.  That explains it :)

Comment: But he still has the TIME and DATA columns in the result in his question.

Answer (score 14):

The suggestion given by @karim79 and @Matthew Jones, that `DISTINCT(ID)` can fix this problem, is a common misconception about the way DISTINCT works in SQL.  It doesn't help, because `DISTINCT` *always* applies to the whole row, not a single column.  The parentheses are irrelevant, as they would be in the queries `SELECT (1)` versus `SELECT 1`.

The answer given by @T Pops is actually helpful in this case, because MySQL handles GROUP BY in a nonstandard way.  See my answer to "[Selecting a Column not in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by/1023435#1023435)" for an explanation.

Another solution is to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` creatively to query for the first row per `ID`.  For instance, *assuming* that the `TIME` column is unique for a given `ID`, you could do the following:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t2
  ON (t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.TIME > t2.TIME)
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL;
```

If `t1` is pointing to the earliest row in the group, then there can be no matching row in t2 with an earlier date.  Therefore, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will find no match, and leave `t2.*` as NULL.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I'll come back and vote you up in about eight hours ;-)

Comment: @Sinan:  Is that a comment that JOIN would have poor performance?  You should try using EXPLAIN to view the optimization plan of a query like this.  Then compare it to the plan for a GROUP BY or DISTINCT query, which usually have to use a temp table.

Comment: @Bill I ran out of votes for today, so I could not upvote your answer. It is important to make the point that DISTINCT is not an appropriate "solution" here. And the rest of your explanation is very clear. There was no sarcasm in my response, just genuine regret that I could not upvote you right at that moment.

Comment: Thanks!  LOL -- I thought you were being snarky, as if you expected the query to take eight hours to finish, and you were waiting for that before casting a vote.  :-)

Comment: this question is not worth a +1 until this is answer is the official solution.

Comment: This is awesome and very clever. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for `GROUP BY`.

You can use a query similar to:

```
SELECT id, time, data GROUP BY ID
```

You'll definitely have to do some tweaking to get that query to work with the structure you have but that's the basic idea.

[Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) has a great reference for using `GROUP BY` with MySQL and PHP.

Comment: +1 This would actually work in MySQL, because MySQL handles GROUP BY in a nonstandard way.

Comment: Is it actually guaranteed to return time + data from the same row?

Comment: No, it makes no guarantee about which row it takes the values from.  In practice, it takes them from the row that is stored physically first.  If that's what the OP wants, then he can use that (assuming MySQL doesn't change behavior in a future version).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by/1023435#1023435

Comment: But once it picks a row, it will take all columns from that row?  It wouldn't take time from row 1 and data from row 4?

Comment: Andomar, it should take whichever row was physically first in the DB. I believe rows are stored with all the columns together so there's no way for row 1's DATA column to come before row 2's DATA column. I think the asker's question is too vague for a definitive answer but this is as close as I could come.

Comment: The tricky part is when you have aggregate functions like MAX() in your query.  The non-aggregated columns still take their values from the first row in the group, even if that isn't the row with the MAX() value.

Comment: Anyway, it's moot because the OP's actual problem is totally different from what he asked.  >:-[

Answer (score 0):

Add a real primary key to the table, maybe called RealId.

Then you can:

```
select *
from YourTable
where realid in (
    select min(realid)
    from YourTable
    group by id
)
```

Which would give you one row per id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

The SQL Query would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ID), TIME, DATA FROM TableName
```

Comment: That would select both records (1,'2009-05-16','x'),(1,'2009-04-11','y') because they differ in TIME and DATA.

Comment: I KNEW i forgot something.  Thanks!

Comment: Which is why I don't program in MySQL; it's too permissive.  Oh well.

Comment: @Matthew Jones: This has nothing to do with MySQL.  DISTINCT works the same in standard SQL as it does in MySQL, or any other brand of database.  DISTINCT *always* applies to the whole row, not to a single column, even if you use parentheses.