# php mysql join and count

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables `imagesgroup` and `images`

`imagesgroup` has following fields `id` and `group_name`

`images` has following fields `id` ,`image_name` and `category` in which we store `imagesgroup.id`

Now i want to show all image groups along with number of images for each image group.

i.e i want to display something like this

group_name  | no. of items in that group

home         |10

Office | 5

Party | 0

please help me out
thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT group_name, COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)
FROM imagesgroup ig
LEFT JOIN images i ON (ig.id = i.category)
GROUP BY ig.id, ig.group_name
```

Comment: You shouldn't select columns that aren't being grouped by. Your results can be inconsistant. This answer goes into a little more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1023435/1056965

Comment: In this case it shouldn't be. I know it can be inconsistant, but the `group_name` is the same for each possible row the query gets grouped by, so there should be no inconsistencies, in fact it follows what is suggested in the accepted answer of the question you linked.

Comment: Glad to hear you're aware. I figured I'd pass the knowledge on just in case. I didn't know until it ended up causing issues for me.

Comment: You were right pointing it out, since I forgot to mention it in my answer, which I have now updated =)

Comment: This is poor, if not terrible, practice. Just because MySQL allows you to select columns that are not in the aggregate does not make it correct.

Comment: Now it should adhere the standards.

Comment: it has a problem, when i have groups with no images, its not showing all such groups

Comment: Try it now, I have updated it with a `LEFT JOIN` to handle empty groups.

Comment: Yes, now its working perfectly and accepting answer
Thanks a lot for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers

This is working for me

`SELECT  l.group_name ,l.id, COUNT(ld.category) as COUNT FROM  imagesgroup AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN images AS ld ON ld.category = l.id GROUP BY  l.id ORDER BY l.id`

Above accepted solution is also working perfectly