# How to select just 1 child table item for each parent record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of lists and a table of list items. I want to formulate a query to select just one list item for each item in the lists table. Here's some simple data to illustrate my question:

```
 'lists' table
id   updated   share
--- ---------- -----
1   2013-07-11   1
2   2013-07-13   0
3   2013-07-15   1
4   2013-07-14   0
5   2013-07-14   1

'list_items' table
id l_id description sort likes
-- ---- ----------- ---- -----
1   1    hello       0     3
2   1    goodbye     0     0
3   1    thanks      0     4
4   2    ok          0     0
5   3    love        0     2
6   3    hate        1     1
7   4    celebrate   0     0
8   5    party       0     1
9   5    summer      1     5
10  5    winter      2     2
```

Now say I want to get the first item from each shared list (share = 1). By first I mean if the list items were sorted by 'sort'.

The expected result based on the above data would be:

```
lists.id id l_id description sort likes
-------- -- ---- ----------- ---- -----
   1     1   1    hello       0     3
   3     5   3    love        0     2
   5     8   5    party       0     1
```

**Update:**
I struggled to get my head around the solutions provided by peterm and hims056 and while kayla's solution looked more like something I could follow it didn't return the correct results. Taking ideas from these solutions I had a crack at it myself and came up with

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT lists.id AS listid, lists.share, list_items.* 
    FROM list_items, lists
    WHERE lists.id = l_id
    AND lists.share = 1 
    ORDER BY sort) q
  GROUP BY q.listid
```

This seems to work but as peterm points out, the values for the columns in select clause that are not part of group by clause may be ambiguous.

I though someone would come up with a solution using `LIMIT` as that was the way I was thinking about doing it first. You can return the list ids which allow sharing simply by:

```
SELECT lists.id FROM lists WHERE share = 1
```

and for a given list id you can return the top list item by:

```
SELECT lists.id AS listid, lists.share, list_items.* 
FROM list_items, lists
WHERE lists.id = l_id 
AND lists.id = 1
ORDER BY sort
LIMIT 1
```

But is there a way to put these 2 statements together to return top list item for each list that allows sharing?

Comment: Didn't any answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** To ensure getting first per group with order by `sort` try

```
SELECT q.l_id list_id, q.id, i.description, i.sort, i.likes 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT l_id, id, @n := IF(@g = l_id, @n + 1, 1) n, @g := l_id g
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT i.l_id, i.id
      FROM list_items i JOIN lists l
        ON i.l_id = l.id 
     WHERE l.share = 1
     ORDER BY l_id, sort, id
  ) b CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @g := 0) a
  HAVING n = 1
) q JOIN list_items i 
   ON q.id = i.id
```

Sample output:

```
| LIST_ID | ID | DESCRIPTION | SORT | LIKES |
---------------------------------------------
|       1 |  1 |       hello |    0 |     3 |
|       3 |  5 |        love |    0 |     2 |
|       5 |  8 |       party |    0 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d59d/20)** demo

Comment: OP said: *By first I mean if the list items were sorted by 'sort'* So this query won't work when [sort is 1 where description is hello](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4519f6/1)

Comment: [Still description = hello](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4519f6/10) is coming where we put sort = 1.

Comment: @hims056 Fair enough. Thanks. It's fixed.

Comment: Looks like this works but difficult to get my head around it. I've come up with something simpler: `SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT lists.id AS listid, lists.share, list_items.* 
  FROM list_items, lists
  WHERE lists.id = l_id
  AND lists.share = 1 
  ORDER BY sort) q
GROUP BY q.listid` Is there any flaw in this simpler solution?

Comment: Although mysql allows (in not strict mode) to specify columns in select clause that are not part of group by it's not a very good idea since there's no deterministic way to tell which value will be returned in each group for such columns. Other than that if your solution is working for you it's great. Just post your answer to your question and close it.

Comment: @peterm I see what you're saying, it's basically a bit of a hack but it works in MySQL. The selected answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by) explains it well: _"In practice, it tends to be the value from the row within the group that is physically stored first."_

Comment: @AidanCurran Like I said if it works for you and you're happy with it then it's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lists.id, list_items.id, l_id, description, sort, likes 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM lists WHERE share = 1) lists 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM list_items GROUP BY l_id) list_items 
  ON  lists.id = l_id
```

Comment: Look like it's not selecting the correct list item based on sort order, but I like the simpler approach. I've come up with `SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT lists.id AS listid, lists.share, list_items.* 
  FROM list_items, lists
  WHERE lists.id = l_id
  AND lists.share = 1 
  ORDER BY sort) q
GROUP BY q.listid` but I'm not 100% sure if it's correct

Comment: i think its fine as long as you could display all data you wanted, but please be careful with your join,, try to add another possible input data, and make sure it will display stable result

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get minimum `list_items.id` sorted by `list_items.sort` you need to perform double nested query like this:

```
SELECT tbl.l_id list_id, tbl.minID, li.description, li.sort, li.likes 
FROM list_items li
JOIN
(
    SELECT l.l_id,MIN(l.id) minID FROM list_items l
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT li.l_id,MIN(li.sort) sort FROM list_items li
          JOIN lists l ON li.l_id = l.id WHERE l.share = 1
         GROUP BY li.l_id
    ) l2
    ON l.l_id = l2.l_id
    AND l.sort = l2.sort
    GROUP BY l.l_id
) tbl
ON  li.id = tbl.minID;
```

- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d139/17)
- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4519f6/9) with different values.