# Count Query with Join

Tags: mysql

i have table as

```
Dept

DEPTNO  DNAME   LOC
10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
20  RESEARCH    DALLAS
30  SALES   CHICAGO
40  OPERATIONS  BOSTON
```

and another table as

```
Emp

EMPNO   ENAME   JOB          MGR    HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    12/17/1980  800     NULL     20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    2/20/1981   1600    300      30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    2/22/1981   1250    500      30
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    4/2/1981    2975    NULL     20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    9/28/1981   1250    1400     30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    5/1/1981    2850    NULL     30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    6/9/1981    2450    NULL     10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    12/9/1982   3000    NULL     20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT   NULL    11/17/1981  5000    NULL     10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    9/8/1981    1500    0        30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK       7788    1/12/1983   1100    NULL     20
7900    JAMES   CLERK       7698    12/3/1981   950     NULL     30
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    12/3/1981   3000    NULL     20
7934    MILLER  CLERK       7782    1/23/1982   1300    NULL     10
```

My question : List ALL the department names and their employee count.
Count should include only those employees whose hire date is greater than 1981

Result: should be like this

```
DNAME       EMPCOUNT
ACCOUNTING    1
OPERATIONS    0
RESEARCH      2
SALES         0
```

please help

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DNAME,
       count(emp.deptno) AS EMPCOUNT
FROM DEPT
LEFT JOIN emp ON DEPT.DEPTNO = emp.DEPTNO
WHERE YEAR(hiredate)>1981
GROUP BY emp.deptno
```

Comment: Thanks for the qucik response Sadikhasan..let me try and get back. :)

Comment: Welcome @user3868356 Copy and paste this query and get output

Comment: `group by` followed by `where` ?

Comment: Better now, but still there is problem, although mysql does not show error while doing `group by` on a non selected column but its better to choose the column in the select list. You may use it or not later in the application thats up to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464502/group-by-clause-column-name-without-selecting-it-in-select-list