# How to store SQL Query result in table column

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

I'm aware of the **INSERT INTO** table_name *QUERY*; however, I'm unsure how to go about achieving the desired result in this case.

Here's a slightly contrived example to explain what I'm looking for, but I'm afraid I cannot put it more succiently.

I have two tables in a database designed for a hotel.

**BOOKING** and **CUSTOMER_BOOKING**

Where **BOOKING** contains *PK_room_number, room_type,* etc. and **CUSTOMER_BOOKING** contains *FK_room_number, FK_cusomer_id*

**CUSTOMER_BOOKING** is a linking table (many customers can make many bookings, and many bookings can consist of many customers).

[image: relationship]

Ultimately, in the application back-end I want to be able to list all rooms that have less than 3 customers associated with them. I could execute this a separate query and save the result in the server-side scripting.

However, a more elegant solution (from my point of view) is to store this within the **BOOKING** table itself. That is to add a column no_of_bookings that counts the number of times the current PK_room_number appears as the foreign key FK_room_number within the **CUSTOMER_BOOKING** table. And why do this instead? Because it would be impossible for me to write a single complicated query which will both include the information from all ROOMS, among other tables, and also count the occurrences of bookings, without excluding ROOMS that don't have any bookings. A very bad thing for a hotel website attempting to show free rooms!

So it would look like this

**BOOKING**: PK_room_number (104B) room_type (double) room_price (high), no_of_bookings (3)
**BOOKING**: PK_room_number (108C) room_type (single) room_price (low), no_of_bookings (1)
**CUSTOMER_BOOKING**: FK_room_number (104B) FK_customer_id (4312)
**CUSTOMER_BOOKING**: FK_room_number (104B) FK_customer_id (6372)
**CUSTOMER_BOOKING**: FK_room_number (104B) FK_customer_id (1112)
**CUSTOMER_BOOKING**: FK_room_number (108C) FK_customer_id (9181)

How would I go about creating this?

Comment: `insert into table1 values (select needfields from table2 where yourconditon)`

Comment: Why would a booking have multiple customers? Wouldn't bookings be akin to orders? I wouldn't be a happy camper, if I arrive at check-in and another customer has my same room, or plane seat or rented car!

Comment: @Parfait it *was* contrived, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because it would be impossible for me to write a single complicated
>   query which will both include the information from all ROOMS, among
>   other tables, and also count the occurrences of bookings, without
>   excluding ROOMS that don't have any bookings.

I wouldn't say it's impossible and unless you're running into performance issues, it's easier to implement than adding a new summary column:

```
select b.*, count(cb.room_number) 
from bookings b
left join customer_booking cb on b.room_number = cb.room_number
group by b.room_number
```

Depending on your query may need to use a derived table containing the booking counts for each room instead instead

```
select b.*, coalesce(t1.number_of_bookings,0) number_of_bookings
from bookings b
left join (
    select room_number, count(*) number_of_bookings
    from customer_booking
    group by room_number
) t1 on t1.room_number = b.room_number
```

You have to `left join` the derived table and select `coalesce(t1.number_of_bookings,0)` in case a room does not have any entries in the derived table (i.e. 0 bookings).

A summary column is a good idea when you're running into performance issues with counting the # of bookings each time. In that case I recommend creating `insert` and `delete` triggers on the `customer_booking` table that either increment or decrement the `number_of_bookings` column.

Comment: Forgive me but the MySQL dialect tends to be lenient in not requiring [non-aggregated columns in group by clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by), so the `b*` in first query will fail in other dialects and does not follow ANSI syntax.

Comment: @Parfait Good point. On other databases it's necessary to group by all the columns that need to be selected and it's probably a good habit to get into. Having said that, the question is tagged with MySQL and when all the members of the group are the same, as I believe is the case here, then it's ok to use this feature.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes; the simpler solution was the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a single straight select like this:

```
select DISTINCT 
       b1.room_pk,
       c1.no_of_bookings
  from cust_bookings b1,
       (select room_pk, count(1) as no_of_bookings
          from cust_bookings
         group by room_pk) c1
 where b1.room_pk = c1.room_pk 
 having c1.no_of_bookings < 3
```

Sorry i used my own table names to test it but you should figure it out easily enough. Also, the "having" line is only there to limit the rows returned to rooms with less than 3 bookings. If you remove that line you will get everything and could use the same sql to update a column on the bookings table if you still want to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below solutions.

A simple aggregate query to count the customers per each booking:

```
SELECT b.PK_room_number, Count(c.FK_customer_id) 
FROM Booking b
INNER JOIN Customer_Booking c ON b.PK_room_number = c.FK_room_number
GROUP BY b.PK_room_number
HAVING Count(c.FK_customer_id) < 3;  # ADD 3 ROOM MAX FILTER
```

And if you intend to use a new column `no_of_booking`, here is an update query (using aggregate subquery) to run right after inserting new value from web frontend:

```
UPDATE Booking b 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT b.PK_room_number, Count(c.FK_customer_id) As customercount
   FROM Booking b
   INNER JOIN Customer_Booking c ON b.PK_room_number = c.FK_room_number
   GROUP BY b.PK_room_number) As r
ON b.PK_room_number = r.PK_room_number
SET b.no_of_booking = r.customercount;
```

Answer (score 0):

the following generates a list showing all of the bookings and a flag of 0 or 1 if the the room has a customer for each of the rooms.  it will display some rooms multiple times if there are multiple customers.

select BOOKING.*, 
case CUSTOMER_BOOKING.FK_ROOM_NUMBER is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BOOKING_FLAG
from BOOKING LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_BOOKING
ON BOOKING.PK_room_numer = CUSTOMER_BOOKING.FK_room_number

summing and grouping we arrive at:

select BOOKING.*, 
SUM(case when CUSTOMER_BOOKING.FK_ROOM_NUMBER is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS BOOKING_COUNT
from BOOKING LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_BOOKING
ON BOOKING.PK_room_number = CUSTOMER_BOOKING.FK_room_number 
GROUP BY BOOKING.PK_room_number

there are at least two other solutions I can think of off the top of my head...