# MySQL Join to Count Transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm sorry if this has been posted before/similarly, I wasn't sure how to structure my question to find proper results.

Essentially, I have 2 tables. `Customers` and `Orders`. I'm trying to pull the customer name from the Customers table, `customerName`, and the amount of orders each customer has made. The Orders table has unique order ID's for every order placed, so my idea was to do a count on each order that belongs to each indiviual customer. Essentially, I want my query to output 2 columns, `Customer name` and `Number of Orders`. Then, I only want to display the customers that have greater than or equal to 5 orders.

These are the tables I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  customerNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  customerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  salesRepEmployeeNumber INTEGER NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber),
  FOREIGN KEY (salesrepEmployeeNumber) references Employees(employeeNumber)
)ENGINE=innodb;

CREATE TABLE Orders (
  orderNumber int(11) NOT NULL,
  orderDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  customerNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderNumber), 
  FOREIGN KEY (customerNumber) references Customers(customerNumber)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

The query I was trying is:

```
SELECT
    c.customerName as 'Customer Name',
    count(o.orderNumber) as 'Number of Orders Made',
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o;
    ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
HAVING count(o.orderNumber) > '4';
```

However, this is just showing 1 single customer having what I believe is all orders attributed to them.

This is an example of the output I'm tring to obtain:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Bw0.png]

Comment: Post your  sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *aggregate* by customer here, i.e. use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    c.customerName,
    COUNT(o.orderNumber) AS num_orders
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
GROUP BY
    c.customerNumber
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 5;
```

One note here is that we aggregate by the `customerNumber` column, since this value is unique to each customer (the `customerName` may be duplicated across customers).  However, we are free to select the `customerName`, because it is functionally determined by the `customerNumber`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to working with MySQL and did not know of Group By. This will help me look into this more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c.customerName as 'Customer Name',
    count(o.orderNumber) as 'Number of Orders Made',
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o;
    ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber, c.customerName
HAVING count(o.orderNumber) > 4;
```

See  [MySQL group by on mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) for insights.

Comment: Grouping by the customer name is not ideal, q.v. my answer for a better version of this query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I am new to MySQL and was unaware of what Group By did. Thanks for the link, I'll definitely look into it more.

Comment: You're correct @TimBiegeleisen, but you will need the name too in the grouping.

Comment: @cdaiga No, you don't.  Because `customerNumber` is the primary key of that table.  You may select _any_ column from `Customers` if you group by the `customerNumber` primary key.

Comment: Yeah I see, it's not necessary in MySQL, but in Oracle. Adding it will still produce the same result as yours.

Comment: @cdaiga It isn't needed in Oracle, either, as far I as know.  The ANSI 92 standard allows selecting non aggregate columns with `GROUP BY` if they are _functionally dependent_ on the column in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Because we `GROUP BY` the primary key column, therefore the values of any other column are uniquely determined, so it's OK (even on Oracle).  You are right though, if grouping by a non primary key column, then it's wrong to select non aggregate columns.

Comment: Thank you very much @TimBiegeleisen for the insight. I have learned something new today about group by.

Comment: I upvoted you, and check out Bill Karwin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by).  I couldn't find an actual doc reference, but this is pretty close.