# Different SUM from different table in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

may I ask for assistance regarding this code, getting different SUM() from different tables doesn't seem to work in this code. Apologies for this matter as I completely forgot how to do this anymore.

It only works when I only use sum for attendance query.

```
$sql = "SELECT *, 

        SUM(num_hr) AS total_hr, 
        attendance.employee_id AS empid, 
        employees.employee_id AS employee, 
        position.description AS job_description, 
        SUM(deductions.amount) AS total_amount_deduction

        FROM attendance

        LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=attendance.employee_id 
        LEFT JOIN position ON position.id=employees.position_id 
        LEFT JOIN deductions ON deductions.deduction_id=employees.deduction_id 

        WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'

        GROUP BY attendance.employee_id

        ORDER BY employees.lastname ASC, employees.firstname ASC";
```

I was hoping to get the results, but its showing different SUM values on every result.

When I remove `SUM(deductions.amount) AS total_amount_deduction` and `LEFT JOIN deductions ON deductions.deduction_id=employees.deduction_id` it works fine.

Comment: Does the query work if you don't select the `*`?

Comment: Your grouping clause is wrong , have to include the other columns employees.employee_id, position.description

Comment: When you use group by, each column in the select clause must be either defined via an Aggregate function (like MAX, MIN, AVG, ...) or must be included in the group by clause... amend the GROUP BY as 
`GROUP BY attendance.employee_id, employees.employee_id, position.description` and mentioned the columns in * explicitly in group by

Comment: Not necessarily. MySQL allows selecting non-group-by columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by.

Comment: @MJoy i did that, but still it doesn't work. I'm still getting wrong values from SUM().

Comment: @Yang it doesn't seem to work when removing *.

Comment: @pjustindaryll are you sure it doesn't work removing star

Comment: @kirangadhe yes. is my structure wrong? I feel like this will cause a problem someday even if this will work. If I will get similar deduction_id from different employees, it will be a problem.