# SQL GROUP BY WITH DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am relatively new to SQL...

I am creating a summary of returned items and I would like the finished result to show the item code, the amount returned (SUM) and the reason for return. So Ideally it would be something like this:

```
101 - Blue Widget | 13 | Shipment Lost
101 - Blue Widget | 3  | Damaged in Transit
102 - Red Widget | 5 | Shipment Lost
```

So it is grouping by ITEM and RMACODE and summing the quantities

Here is a simplified version of the query I wrote for this

```
Select ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY), RMACODE, DATEENTERED
FROM RMAITEMS
group by ITEM, Quantity, RMACODE
```

I am loading this in SSRS and need DATENETERED for my report parameters to only pull records between @StartDate and @EndDate. I get en error saying DATEENTERED is invalid because it is not in the GROUP BY.

Is there a better/different way to acheive the result I am looking for?

Thanks

Andrew

I made the changes suggested by edkloczko and it appeared everything would work then, but since we removed the date from the select statement I am unable to use it in my report parameters. Here is a screenshot. I have a few ideas I will try out today but if anyone has already climbed this hill and can help me with directions I would be grateful.

[Expression Needed is Absent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezL51.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Selecting a Column not in Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023347/mysql-selecting-a-column-not-in-group-by)

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  An appropriate database tag (sql-server) is also warranted.

Comment: diziaq, I don't think it does.

Comment: Gordon, Sorry, I thought the section with the 101- Blue Widget | 13 | Shipment Lost was my desired result and would imply the sample data. I will try to add more detail.

Comment: Why do you want to add the DATEENTERED column to your GROUP BY clause?

Comment: briskovich, as far as I know, if i don't i can't use it to filter the results with parameters in srss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to filter by date and don't actually need the date field...

```
SELECT ITEM, SUM(QUANTITY), RMACODE
FROM RMAITEMS
WHERE DATEENTERED>=STARTDATE AND DATEENTERED<=ENDDATE
GROUP BY ITEM, QUANTITY, RMACODE
```

This will give you all the records you need and makes the extra filtering step you're doing unnecessary - it will only select the records between the start and end dates.

I've run into the same issue before with our IBM DB2. As far as I know you need to specify ALL of the SELECT items in the GROUP BY statement. Unsure if this is specific to certain databases or not.

Comment: I think this worked, I am having some issues with the parameters in Visual Studio now but I once I get that figured out I will update. Thanks

Comment: This particular format works for the database I primarily work with because the date format is  a number (20200520 for today's date), you may have to tweak it if your date is a string or datetime format.

Comment: That was what I needed, It required me to change some things in the UI in Visual Studio but once I got it all figured out the report was exactly what i needed. That you so much, you gave me a better shot at having a job next week! Thanks